# How to rename a column for a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

below is part code:

```
df = None

F_DATE = ['202101', '202102', '202103']

for date in F_DATE:
    if df is None:
        df = spark.sql("select count(*) as Total_count from test_" + date)
    else:
        df2 = spark.sql("select count(*) as Total_count from test_" + date)
        df = df.union(df2)

df.write.csv('/csvs/test.csv')
```

I tried 'toDF()', 'withColumnRenamed()', and 'selectExpr()', but the column name was not changed.

**NOTE. Use the table in Hive.**

**ADD**
I've never used "df.show()" to write code, and I've used "df.show()" to read code. When used "df.show()" in write code, it was confirmed that the column name came out well, and when used "df.show()" in read code, it was confirmed that the column name did not come out properly.

Comment: which column do you want to rename? and to what name?

Comment: @ScootCork The result above is the column name '_c0'. I want to change the column name '_c0' to 'Total_count'.

Comment: You should enable headers to have same dataframe column names in CSV . `df.write.option('header', True).csv('/csvs/test.csv')`

Comment: @Mohana B C thx for your comment. when i use that option, column name is not change. However, it was confirmed that the set column name was in the value, not the column.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I had a problem with the column name when I read. The problem was solved by specifying schema as StructureType in the code to read. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```py
df = df.withColumnRenamed('old_name', 'new_name')
```

Comment: thx... but, i already try that. and... it's not working..

Comment: @SecY what's the error message?

Comment: there is no error message. i apply "df = df.withColumnRenamed('col1', 'col2')" code before "df.write.csv('/csvs/test.csv')" code. Is this order wrong?

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I had a problem with the column name when I read. The problem was solved by specifying schema as StructureType in the code to read. Thank you.